# What is the best way to do a static dispatch, bytecode generated proxy in java nowadays?

Tags: java, bytecode

I have ued cglib in th epast, but frankly I have to believe there is a more convenient way than the callback array and callback filter approach in cglib. I know there used to be an aspectwerkz proxy,. but it seems to have wandered away somewhere.

Comment: The answers so far focus on doing bytecode generation via compiling source code, which is very fine and dandy, but I am primarily looking for a replacement of the dynamic proxy which can avoid a map based dispatch inside the invocation handler.

Comment: You described your old solution, but not the actual problem. I have the strong feeling that there are much better solutions than the current answers offer, but it requires a more specific description of the actual task to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want simple proxies with minimal amount of mucking with bytecode, try janino ( http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home ):

```
final String bodyText=
"public Object get(Object obj) {return null;}\n"+
"public void set(Object obj, Object val) {}\n"+
"public Class getPropertyType() {return Void.class;}\n"+
"public boolean isPrimitive() {return true;}\n";

return (PropHandle)
   ClassBodyEvaluator.createFastClassBodyEvaluator(
   new Scanner(target+"__"+property, new StringReader(bodyText)),
   PropHandle.class, // Base type to extend/implement
   (ClassLoader)null); // Use current thread's context class loader
```

That's a snippet from my ORM which generates accessors.

If you really wish to work on byte-code level, try Javassist - it has fairly nice interface.

Comment: Janino is great, too, but doesn't really do what I am looking for. My main goal is to get the equivalent of static dispatch from a dynamic proxy, not to generate arbitrary classes.

Comment: Why not just generate the dispatch method's text? Or am I missing something?

Comment: true, guess you can, but... ick :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) allows programming bytecode with using Java code snippets:

```
CtClass point = ClassPool.getDefault().get("Point");
CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make(
             "public int xmove(int dx) { x += dx; }",
             point);
point.addMethod(m);
```

Comment: Javassist is great, but doesn't really do what I am looking for. My main goal is to get the equivalent of static dispatch from a dynamic proxy, not to generate arbitrary classes.

Comment: You can generate static dispatch with Javassist as well. What's the question?